# using strtok and populating array

Tags: c, strtok

I am populating an array of tokens from input from stdin. I was looking at a tutorial, and the code successfully populates an array, however, I am not being able to use if else condition to eliminate the token I don't want to put in the array.

```
char * token[MAX_ARGS];                    
char ** arg;                              
while(fgets(line, MAX_BUFFER, stdin)) {

    arg = token;
    *arg++ = strtok(line," \t\n"); 
    while ((*arg++ = strtok(NULL, " \t\n")));
```

can i get some pointer on how I can break that while loop in last line, so that i can use if else.

Comment: Just what do you gain by cramming all that into one line?  Unreadable code subject to subtle bugs in order to win [the International Obfuscated C Contest](https://www.ioccc.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is cleaner to do it like this

```
char *tok = strtok(line, " \t\n");
while(tok) {
    *arg++ = tok;
    tok = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
}
```

Now the `NULL` pointer isn't placed in the array.

But, you aren't keeping any tally of how many pointers are in the array, so why don't you want the sentinel value `NULL`?